# Fail in easy list manipulation

Tags: haskell

Using GHCi I do the following :

```
prelude> let lol [] = []
prelude> let lol (x:xs) = (lol xs) ++ [x]
```

When I try to evaluate

```
prelude> lol [1, 2, 3]
```

I get

```
 Exception: <interactive>:3:5-32: Non-exhaustive patterns in function lol
```

I think I understand the problem (list with 1 element not matched ?) but can't see why he can't match x:xs as x:[]

Comment: `let lol xs = case xs of [] -> [] ; (x:xs) -> lol xs ++ [x]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
prelude> let lol [] = []
```

defines a function of type `[a] -> [b]` that will produce a pattern-match failure when passed a non-empty list. That definition is then shadowed by

```
prelude> let lol (x:xs) = (lol xs) ++ [x]
```

of type `[a] -> [a]`, which will cause a pattern-match failure when its argument is an empty list.

`let` bindings are not incremental, a new binding for a name shadows the old binding.

You can define a function with several clauses by separating the clauses with a semicolon,

```
let lol [] = []; lol (x:xs) = lol xs ++ [x]
```

Answer (score 5):

The second `let` statement "overwrote" the first -- in the same way as if you used multiple `let`s in `do`-notation.

You can use ghci's multi-line syntax operators, `:{` and `:}`:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let 
Prelude|   lol [] = []
Prelude|   lol (x:xs) = (lol xs) ++ [x]
Prelude| :}
Prelude> lol []
[]
Prelude> lol [1,2,3]
[3,2,1]
```